# On Scala sheet: Type ';' expected but ')' found

Tags: scala, scala-ide

In Eclipse Scala sheet I get error for:

```
(-1 until 5).foreach {i =>    println(i)}
```

Errors are:

```
Type ';' expected but ')' found
illegal start of simple expression
```

but if I delete the "." after (-1 until 5) I won't get any error:

```
(-1 until 5) foreach {i =>    println(i)}
```

why is that?

Comment: This works fine in the Scala REPL. The problem is your IDE.

Comment: ^^^ Yep, works fine in IntelliJ.

Comment: you can report a bug here: https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets